# MapStruct Mapper as Spring Framework Converter - idiomatic use possible?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I'd like to combine `MapStruct` mappers with Spring's [Conversion model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#core-convert). So I declare every `Mapper` interface as an extension of Spring's `Converter`:

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper extends Converter<Car, CarDto> {    
    @Override
    CarDto convert(Car car);    
}
```

I can then use the mapper beans by injecting the standard `ConversionService`:

```
class CarWarehouse {
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    ...

    public CarDto getCarInformation(Car car) {
        return conversionService.convert(car, CarDto.class);
    }
}
```

This works nicely, but I'm wondering whether there's a way to avoid injecting some Mappers into others directly via the `uses` attribute. What I'd like to do is tell a Mapper to `use` the `ConversionService` for employing another mapper. However, since the `ConversionService`'s `convert` method doesn't match MapStruct's standard pattern for a mapping method, the code generation plugin doesn't recognise that it can use the service when looking for a submapping. Basically, what I want to do is write

```
@Mapper(uses=ConversionService.class)
public interface ParentMapper extends Converter<Parent, ParentDto>
```

instead of

```
@Mapper(uses={ChildMapper1.class, ChildMapper2.class, ChildMapper3.class})
public interface ParentMapper extends Converter<Parent, ParentDto>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit**

Since it's been asked, let's say I've got a `CarMapper` defined as above, with the types `Car` and `CarDto` having an attribute `wheel` of type `Wheel` and `WheelDto`, respectively. Then I'd like to be able to define another Mapper like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface WheelMapper extends Converter<Wheel, WheelDto> {    
    @Override
    WheelDto convert(Wheel wheel);    
}
```

Right now, I'd have to add this Mapper explicitly:

```
@Mapper(uses = WheelMapper.class)
public interface CarMapper extends Converter<Car, CarDto>
```

Which would then give the generated `CarMapperImpl` an `@Autowired` member of type `WheelMapper` which would be called in order to map the attribute `wheel`.

However, what I'd like is that the generated code would look somewhat like this:

```
@Component
public class CarMapperImpl implements CarMapper {
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;
    @Override
    public CarDto convert(Car car) {
        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();
        carDto.setWheel(conversionService.convert(car.getWheel(), WheelDto.class);
        return carDto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's been more than a year since I asked this question, but now we've come up with an answer inside the MapStruct project itself - the [MapStruct Spring Extensions](https://mapstruct.org/news/2020-12-03-mapstruct-spring-extensions-0-0-1-released/) project.

A [`CarMapper` example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-spring-extensions/tree/master/examples/noconfig/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/extensions/spring/example/noconfig) is provided as an example within the project.

Comment: This Stack Overflow answer would be improved with an inline code example of use solving the OP's specific question.  I don't have the time at the moment to play around with it and test it out to make sure it works, and I don't want to post it without making sure it's good.

Answer (score 1):

You can just skip passing a `WheelMapper` entirely, when you just have a `CarMapper` the generated `CarMapperImpl` will contain a logic to map `Wheel` <-> `WheelDto` as well. No need to pass anything to `uses`, making your issue obsolete.

```
carDto.setWheel( wheelToWheelDto( car.getWheel() ) );
```

with a method like;

```
protected WheelDto wheelToWheelDto(Wheel wheel) {
    if ( wheel == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    WheelDto wheelDto = new WheelDto();

    wheelDto.setName( wheel.getName() );

    return wheelDto;
}
```

---

I did try to achieve an intelligent injection of `ConversionService` through `MapStruct`, but it is not possible I think. You'd need support from `MapStruct` to achieve such a feat. It does not even consider injecting `ConversionService`. Maybe a custom generic mapper that is already implemented and uses `ConversionService` might work, but I was unable to do that! Though I don't see any reason for it since `MapStruct` is already creating all necessary smaller mappers from the parent mapper...

Comment: What about attributes that are shared between different master types? Let's say there's a Van with type Wheel as well. In these situations, I typically do specify separate mappers for these shared types. I know the example isn't absolutely convincing, but there are situations where it just comes natural to do so.

Comment: @Ray you can have a `Wheel` class, then extend it and have `VanWheel`, and `CarWheel` maybe? There are other solutions to that issue, but overall I'd suggest sticking with what `MapStruct` has without any hack solution

Comment: @Ray plus with what you are trying to do, you'll have to pass `ConversionService` to both `VanMapper` & `CarMapper`, how can it guess that one has to use mapper1 and other mapper2 for `Wheel` fields other that specifically setting different classes for it as I suggested?

Comment: There is a way to achieve what you're explaining in the final paragraph with some additional effort. I'll see if I can explain this in more detail when I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I doubt you can achieve automatic wiring of `ConversionService` into generated mappers by `MapStruct`. The way that you described in the question (that wires individual mappers through `uses` annotation attribute), probably, the best that `MapStruct` can give out of the box.

However, there is ***workaround***, if you absolutely need to use `ConversionService` to perform conversion for some DTOs (e.g. if you have some legacy converters, that you don't want to refactor to mappers). Basically, you can use combination of `Mappers.getMapper` static factory to get instance of `ConversionService` and `default` method in the mapper interface, to use `ConversionService` instance:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CarMapper extends Converter<Car, CarDto> {

    ConversionService CONVERSION_SERVICE = Mappers.getMapper(ConversionService.class);

    @Override
    default CarDto convert(Car car) {
        if (car == null) {
            return null;
        }

        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();

        carDto.setEngine(CONVERSION_SERVICE.convert(car.getEngine(), EngineDto.class));
        carDto.setWheel(CONVERSION_SERVICE.convert(car.getWheel(), WheelDto.class));

        return carDto;
    }
}
```

**Note**: as you can see, workaround requires to write `CarMapper` code. So, in my opinion, the solution with `uses` annotation attribute is cleaner approach. For example, you get almost the same result, by defining following interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", 
        uses = {EngineMapper.class, WheelMapper.class}, 
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface CarMapper extends Converter<Car, CarDto> {
    @Override
    CarDto convert(Car car);
```

Generated mapper:

```
@Component
public class CarMapperImpl implements CarMapper {

    private final EngineMapper engineMapper;
    private final WheelMapper wheelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public CarMapperImpl(EngineMapper engineMapper, WheelMapper wheelMapper) {

        this.engineMapper = engineMapper;
        this.wheelMapper = wheelMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public CarDto convert(Car car) {
        if (car == null) {
            return null;
        }

        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();

        carDto.setEngine(engineMapper.convert(car.getEngine()));
        carDto.setWheel(wheelMapper.convert(car.getWheel()));

        return carDto;
    }
}
```

Comment: As for the existing mechanisms, you're probably right. The easiest way is just to ignore the `ConversionService` for the child mappers altogether. However, MapStruct gurus came up with another idea in the Gitter chat. I'll see if I can find some time to explain this in a separate post.

Comment: Cool! Can you share the link to the Gitter? Just interested to find the better way - it's frequent use-case for me also.

Comment: It involves writing your own additional Annotation Processor to generate a "bridge class": https://gitter.im/mapstruct/mapstruct-users